# Express Web API https server crashing on first request

Tags: node.js, api, express, server

I am running a development Web API server on Node.js in Express environment. The server uses the Greenlock module for automatic Let's Encrypt certificate issuance.

When I run **npm start prod**, de server starts successfully and from the console log I can see that the server is listening on ports 80 and 443 for https connections:

Listening on 0.0.0.0:80 for ACME challenges, and redirecting to HTTPS
Listening on 0.0.0.0:443 for secure traffic
Ready to Serve:
web*****.club
ACME Directory URL: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory

The NameSilo domain web*****.club points to my router's public ip address through an A record, and in the router, port 443 is mapped to port 443 and forwarded to one of the computers on my LAN where the API server resides.

As soon as I make a https API request from a webpage, the server crashes and it produces the following output:

Error cert_issue:
read ECONNRESET
code: ECONNRESET
Error: read ECONNRESET
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20)

The certificate issuance seems to be ok, because in the .config/acme dir the Let's Encrypt certificate with the private and the public key is added directly after the https request.

---

(Edit)

The server works, when accessed over https locally, and also when accessed locally over http.

It now also works from the domain name. I made a https server for port 443, without Greenlock, issued certificate cert.key/pem with help of openssl:

openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout cert.key -out cert.pem -sha256

used the following code in server.ts:

```
const express = require('express');
var app = require("../dist/app.js");
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const port = 443

const httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./security/cert.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./security/cert.pem')
}
const server = https.createServer(httpsOptions, app)
    .listen(port, () => {
        console.log('https server running on localhost at ' + port)
    })
```

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Could you show some code?

Comment: Does your server work when accessed over https locally (not going through the router)?  Does your server work locally over http?  These tests are about narrowing down where the problem is so you can focus further debugging in the right place.